# Why we can't add character at certain position by charAt(index) in java

Tags: java, string

```
public class ReverseString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "mnop";
        s.charAt(0) = 'l';
    }
}
```

Comment: Because Strings are immutable in java. Once created, they don't change. Look at `StringBuilder`s instead.

Answer (score 3):

Java only allows you to assign to variables, fields and array elements.

The result of a method - like `s.charAt(0)` - is none of these, so you can't assign to it.

The reason for this is down to the way Java returns: it returns by value, not by reference, and that value only exists temporarily. As such, if you were able to assign it, the side effect of that assignment is immediately lost, making it pointless.

It's also true that `String` is immutable; but this  limitation on what you can assign to is the reason you couldn't do this even for some notional `MutableString` class you might try to create.

Comment: Well, I agree with what you're saying, but if the OP was using the proper type, he might have also found setCharAt(), insert() and the rest of them.. I think he's just mapping `str.charAt(i) <==> str[i]` from some other language.. Anyway, you get +1 from me..

Answer (score 2):

Strings in java are immutable, meaning they can't change at all.

To do something like this, use a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("mnop");
sb.setCharAt(0, 'l');

//later, you probably want to get back to a String:
String s = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Yes, strings are immutable, but you couldn't do what OP is trying to do even with a "`MutableString`" class.

Answer (score 1):

`s.charAt(0)` returns a `char` value, not a `char` variable to which you could assign a value.

And anyway, `String` is immutable, so you can't modify the value of an existing `String`.

You can obtain a copy of the array of all the characters of the `String`, and modify that array:

```
String s = "mnop";
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
chars[0]= 'l';
```

However, this doesn't modify the original `String`, since it's immutable.

You can create a new `String` using that array though:

```
String newS = new String(chars);
```

Answer (score 1):

`charAt` returns a `char` that's a copy of the character at that position in the string. It's not a reference back to the original string, which is immutable.

You could use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead, though:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("mnop");
sb.setCharAt(0, 'l');
String s = sb.toString();
```